# Detect noise with Codename One

Tags: codenameone, detect

I'm using Codename one, Instead of using a bonton, i want to execute an action when I detect a breath (sound), how can i detect the breath please ?

```
Button btn0 = new Button("Back");
btn0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Codenameone is yet to have an API for accessing device microphone, this is something you can implement through native interface.

Read about native interface [here](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-interface.html)

Comment: To clarify slightly we do have `MediaManager.createMediaRecorder` but it will show a recording interface and won't provide direct microphone access.